# Dynamic indexed multidimensional array print in foreach loop and print in table

Tags: php, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array, foreach

I am having multiple indexed array,here the index changing dynamically.Actually the index of the arrays are id's of group.How can i pass these array in to `foreach` loop

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [462] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [group_name] => First
                            [invoice_no] => 

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [invoice_no] => 
                            [invoice_no] => 2Q

                        )

                )

            [525] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [group_name] => Second
                            [invoice_no] => 

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [group_name] => 
                            [invoice_no] => 3QW

                        )

                )


        )

)
```

This is my array structure,Please help me to print results using `foreach` loop in php with out changing array structure
I am trying this code

```
foreach ($Sale_list_array as $key => $value) {
    echo ($key);

    echo $value[$key][group_name];
}
```

But,this won't fix my problem. I am hoping output like this in table structure

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<td>Group</td>
<td>Invoice</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td>First</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>2Q</td></tr>
<tr><td>Second</td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td>3QW</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you show your expected output?

Comment: So what is the exact problem? Where's the code that you have tried?

Comment: Also which array are you hoping to loop over?

Comment: `$arrayVariable[$keyVariable] = $valueVariable;`this will create your array with dynamic key and value

Comment: so you want `$key` as key of new array and `$value[$key][group_name]` as value?

Comment: Yes,that is exactly my problem -@ParitoshMahale

Comment: which one is `$Sale_list_array` ?

Comment: I just added html side output - @PankajMakwana

Comment: in all case every key has 2 array value?

Comment: I am taking about `[0] => Array
                        (
                            [group_name] => Second
                            [invoice_no] => 

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [group_name] => 
                            [invoice_no] => 3QW

                        )` portion.

Comment: yes..-@Avishake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code below, `$wholeArr` is variable which holds your full array value

```
     foreach( $wholeArr as $group ){
        foreach( $group as $groupKey => $groupValues ){
           foreach( $groupValues as $groupVal ){
             echo $groupVal["group_name"]."<br/>";
           }
         }
       }
```

Comment: @ubm No mention, happy to hear that your problem is solved,

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$newArray = array();
foreach ($Sale_list_array as $key => $value) {
   $newArray[$key] = $value[$key][group_name];
}
print_r($newArray)
```

Comment: you are trying to access index 0 which is not exist show me your code what you tried

Comment: `echo $Sale_list_array[0][462][0]['group_name']`,then i got first

Comment: this will only return first group_name as you are using static key's. You need to use foreach for dynamically travel through array

Comment: oh.. i solved the problem using double `foreach` loop,ok thanks